# Are device IOs handled even when a device is not opened by any process?

Tags: linux, posix

The following shell program examples makes the question clearer.

Given a simple character device (a ftdi ttyUSB device in my case), I send it a request with `echo` to `open();write();close();` the device, then read the answer with `cat` to `open();read();close();` the device, with two distinct processes (`/bin/echo` and `/bin/cat`).

1. The following works:

> ```
> $ /bin/echo -ne $request > /dev/ttyUSB0 ; /bin/cat -e < /dev/ttyUSB0 
> M-^?^B^@^C
> ```

2. The following does not work:

> ```
> $ /bin/echo -ne $request > /dev/ttyUSB0 ; sleep 2s ; /bin/cat -e < /dev/ttyUSB0 
> cat does not read anything
> ```

3. Another working example:

> ```
> $ /bin/cat -e < /dev/ttyUSB0 & sleep 2s ; /bin/echo -ne $request > /dev/ttyUSB0
> M-^?^B^@^C
> ```

What happens in `2`? Why is the behavior different? Where did the data go?

Comment: Your choice of using a terminal device (e.g. /dev/tty*) complicates an answer because terminal input is buffer several times and is highly processed (i.e. line discipline).  BTW You haven't indicated whether you installed a loopback jumper, so the "input" you're "reading" would presumably be a local echo generated by the terminal subsystem (i.e. it's not output that's then received by the serial port)..

Comment: The tty is set in non-canonical mode in my case. So no echoing, no buffering and no line editing.

Comment: *"The tty is set in non-canonical mode in my case. So no echoing.."*  -- Non-canonical input & output processing is independent of echo settings.  *"... no buffering ..."* -- If you have actually studied the kernel driver code, then you would realize that's a ridiculous assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data quite literally went nowhere. Nobody was listening for it, so it was discarded. The exact mechanics depend on the hardware, but typically the first open of a device clears any receive buffers in the hardware, though there's no guarantee those buffers are even enabled.

Comment: How do you explain `1.` then? The sequence of syscalls is the same but without sleeping.

Comment: In case 1, the data was received by the hardware after the device was opened for the second time.

Comment: It makes sense since my device is much slower than the CPU. Does POSIX specifies what the state of device transfers should be when opening it? I'm trying to get rid of ongoing requests of processes killed (i.e. the device is answering). The kernel still receives data even when flushing the device and then kernel fifos, which means that the data is already sent by the device and in transit somewhere in the IO tree (usb device -> usb host -> pci)...). I am shocked by how hard it is to find a solution to this very simple and common case: how to get a clean overall RX/TX state, both SW and HW...

Comment: It's very device and protocol specific. If the protocol has some kind of ping you can send, you can wait for a response and then consider both ends in synch. If not, you can send a bunch of things that get a response. The protocol docs should say how to establish sync.